# xcode CollectionViewController scrollToItemAtIndexPath not working

Tags: xcode

I have created a `CollectionView` Control and filled it with images. Now I want to scroll to item at a particular index on start. I have tried out `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` as follows:

```
[self.myFullScreenCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath 
atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];
```

However, I am getting following exception. Could anyone guide me on where am I going wrong.

```
2013-02-20 02:32:45.219 ControlViewCollection1[1727:c07] *** Assertion failure in 
-[UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17
/UICollectionViewData.m:485 2013-02-20 02:32:45.221 ControlViewCollection1[1727:c07] must return a 
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance from -layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath: for path 
<NSIndexPath 0x800abe0> 2 indexes [0, 4]
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Whether it's a bug or a feature, UIKit throws this error whenever  `scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:Animated` is called before `UICollectionView` has laid out its subviews.

As a workaround, move your scrolling invocation to a place in the view controller lifecycle where you're sure it has already computed its layout, like so:

```
@implementation CollectionViewControllerSubclass

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // scrolling here doesn't work (results in your assertion failure)
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = // compute some index path

    // scrolling here does work
    [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath
                                atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally
                                        animated:YES];
}

@end
```

At the very least, the error message should probably be more helpful. I've opened a [rdar://13416281](http://openradar.appspot.com/13416281); please dupe.

Comment: Don't forget about position values for vertical and horizontal scrolling: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18227362/989896

Comment: This answer saved me so much hair-pulling, thanks! By moving my image size update and reload code into viewDidLayoutSubviews, I also got rid of an annoying collection view warning, so I am doubly in debt.

Comment: I put it in the viewDidApper instead of the viewDidLayoutSubviews, since I want it to scroll only once, not every time the layout is recomputed, but you saved my day.

Comment: Calling `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` in `viewWillAppear` now works (Bug is closed).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42964452/5242940 - this answer is better since scroll will not be performed on each layout of subviews - only for the first time (or whenever you set the flag for flexibility).

Answer (score 53):

If you are trying to scroll when the view controller is loading, make sure to call `layoutIfNeeded` on the `UICollectionView` before you call `scrollToItemAtIndexPath`. This is better than putting the scroll logic in viewDidLayoutSubviews because you won't perform the scroll operation every time the parent view's subviews are laid out.

Comment: I wasted over 3 hours trying to solve this issue, you really saved me. thanks

Comment: Perfect! This saved me a lot of time. Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when using auto layout. I had to set a flag indicating a pending scroll was needed, then check that flag in layoutSubviews in a table view (or viewDidLayoutSubview if using a view controller).

Comment: This really helped. Thank you!

Comment: Is it the correct way to work with `UIViewController` lifecycle? I think we shouldn't call `layoutIfNeeded` in `viewDidLoad` since view controllers do layout later. Seems like it can lead to undefined behaviour in future even if now it works.

Answer (score 15):

Sometimes `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)` is either not called on the main thread, or blocks it, causing `scrollToItem(at:at:animated:)` to not do anything.

Work around this by doing:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Unbelievably WORKED on viewDidLayoutSubviews!!

Comment: That was the only solution here that ALWAYS scrolls to the right item for me. When using `layoutIfNeeded` it would scroll to the wrong position in portrait mode. No idea why.

Comment: This works because you are sending that message to a future time, by the time it gets called, all the other layout is in place, if you use a perform selector after delay will also work.

Answer (score 10):

As of iOS 9.3, Xcode 8.2.1, Swift 3:

Calling `scrollToItem(at:)` from `viewWillAppear()` is still broken, particularly if you are using Section Headers/Footers, Auto Layout, Section Insets.

Even if you call `setNeedsLayout()` and `layoutIfNeeded()` on the `collectionView`, the behavior is still borked. Putting the scrolling code in to an animation block doesn't work reliably.

As indicated in the other answers, the solution is to only call `scrollToItem(at:)` once you are sure everything has been laid out. i.e. in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

However, you need to be selective; you don't want to perform scrolling every time `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` is called. So a solution is to set a flag in `viewWillAppear()`, and act it on it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

i.e.

```
fileprivate var needsDelayedScrolling = false

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.needsDelayedScrolling = true
    // ...
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if self.needsDelayedScrolling {
        self.needsDelayedScrolling = false
        self.collectionView!.scrollToItem(at: someIndexPath,
                at: .centeredVertically,
                animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

U can do this and on viewDidLoad method

just make call preformBatchUpdates

```
[self performBatchUpdates:^{
        if ([self.segmentedDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(segmentedBar:selectedIndex:)]){
            [self.segmentedDelegate segmentedBar:self selectedIndex:_selectedPage];
        }
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished){
            [self scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:_selectedPage inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];
        }

    }];
```

In my case my subclass CollectionView has a property selectedPage, and on a setter of this property i call

```
- (void)setSelectedPage:(NSInteger)selectedPage {
    _selectedPage = selectedPage;
    [self performBatchUpdates:^{
        if ([self.segmentedDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(segmentedBar:selectedIndex:)]){
            [self.segmentedDelegate segmentedBar:self selectedIndex:_selectedPage];
        }
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished){
            [self scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:_selectedPage inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];
        }

    }];
}
```

In view controller i calling this by code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationBar.segmentedPages.selectedPage = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Also remember that you need to use proper UICollectionviewScrollPosition value. Please see code below for clarification:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UICollectionViewScrollPosition) {
UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone                 = 0,

/* For a view with vertical scrolling */
// The vertical positions are mutually exclusive to each other, but are bitwise or-able with the horizontal scroll positions.
// Combining positions from the same grouping (horizontal or vertical) will result in an NSInvalidArgumentException.
UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop                  = 1 << 0,
UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically   = 1 << 1,
UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom               = 1 << 2,

/* For a view with horizontal scrolling */
// Likewise, the horizontal positions are mutually exclusive to each other.
UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft                 = 1 << 3,
UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally = 1 << 4,
UICollectionViewScrollPositionRight                = 1 << 5
```

};

Comment: Wow... this helps me. I set my collectionview to scroll horizontally, but I mistakenly input the UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically. Changed it to UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Adding the scrolling logic to `viewDidAppear` worked for me:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(
        someIndexPath,
        atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.None,
        animated: animated)
}
```

Adding it to `viewDidLoad` doesn't work: it gets ignored.

Adding it to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` doesn't work unless you want to scroll logic calling any time anything changes. In my case, it prevented the user from manually scrolling the item

Comment: Man, you are the savior! I've spent close to two hours without any progress. Finally!

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not the universal solution since `viewDidAppear` is called only when your ViewController's presenting animation finished. It means that the presented ViewController will only scroll to the selected item after the transition animation is finished. In my case I want it to be in the correct collection view position from the very beginning - when the transition animation just started. That is why the answer of @Womble is better.

Comment: @Legonaftik Thanks: it is always great to get more detail on answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
    myCollectionview.scrollToItem(at: myIndexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
}, completion: {
    (value: Bool) in
    // put your completion stuff here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is based on @Womble's answer, all credit goes to them:

The method `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` gets called repeatedly. For me (iOS 11.2) the first time it gets called the `collectionView.contentSize` is `{0,0}`. The second time, the `contentSize` is correct. Therefore, I had to add a check for this:

```
var needsDelayedScrolling = false

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.needsDelayedScrolling = true
    // ...
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if self.needsDelayedScrolling && collectionView.contentSize.width > 0 {
        self.needsDelayedScrolling = false
        self.collectionView!.scrollToItem(at: someIndexPath,
                at: .centeredVertically,
                animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

After adding that extra `&& collectionView.contentSize.width > 0` it works beautifully.

Comment: Is is better to use viewWillLayoutSubviews to set scroll position smoothly.