# Scroll to item in collection view crashes the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I want to scroll to a certain item of an `UICollectionView` inside `viewWillAppear`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [collectionView_ scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex_ inSection:0]
                            atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft
                                    animated:NO];
}
```

On iOS 6 this code crashes the app returning

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UICollectionViewData.m:485
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'must return a UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance from -layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath: for path <NSIndexPath 0x13894e70> 2 indexes [0, 2]'
```

On iOS7 it does not crashes but is simply does nothing.

The scrolling to the correct item only works in `viewDidAppear` but I want to show the screen with the collection in the correct item, on appear. I tried to scroll it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` but it also crashes. Wrapping the call inside a `try-catch` avoids the crash but it still does not working.

What is the point of this? Is it impossible to show the correct item on appear?

Thank you so much.

**EDIT 1**

I printed this on `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (`selectedIndex_` is 2, and the collection has 10 items):

```
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *test = [collectionView_ layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex_ inSection:0]];
```

The result is this in both places.

```
<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x11b9ff20> index path: (<NSIndexPath: 0x11b9c450> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}); frame = (0 0; 0 0);
```

**EDIT 2**

This is the trace I print of the `contentSize` of the collection

```
2013-12-09 08:56:59.300 - didLoad {0, 0}
2013-12-09 08:56:59.315 - willAppear {0, 0}
2013-12-09 08:56:59.350 - viewDidLayoutSubviews {0, 0}
2013-12-09 08:56:59.781 - viewDidLayoutSubviews {3200, 223}
2013-12-09 08:56:59.879 - didAppear {3200, 223}
2013-12-09 08:56:59.882 - viewDidLayoutSubviews {3200, 223}
```

The collection view is created programatically in `viewDidLoad`

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
collectionView_ = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:layout];
[collectionView_ setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[collectionView_ setDelegate:self];
[collectionView_ setDataSource:self];
[collectionView_ setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[collectionView_ setPagingEnabled:YES];
[collectionView_ setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[collectionView_ registerClass:[MyCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:[MyCollectionViewCell collectionCellIdentifier]];
[scrollView_ addSubview:collectionView_];
```

`scrollView_` is created via XIB (the only control in the XIB. I need another scroll to put some other control below the horizontal collection). The constraints of this method are set in `updateViewConstraints`

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints {
    [super updateViewConstraints];

    NSDictionary *views = [self viewsDictionary];
    NSDictionary *metrics = @{ @"bigMargin" : @12, @"collectionViewHeight" : @(collectionViewHeight_) };

    NSMutableString *verticalConstraints = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"V:|[collectionView_(==collectionViewHeight)]"];

    [scrollView_ addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[collectionView_(==scrollView_)]|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:views]];

    if (extendedInformationView_) {

        [scrollView_ addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[extendedInformationView_(==scrollView_)]|"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                            metrics:nil
                                                                              views:views]];

        [verticalConstraints appendFormat:@"-bigMargin-[extendedInformationView_]"];
    }

    if (actionListView_) {

        [scrollView_ addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[actionListView_(==scrollView_)]|"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                            metrics:nil
                                                                              views:views]];

        [verticalConstraints appendFormat:@"-bigMargin-[actionListView_]"];
    }

    [verticalConstraints appendString:@"-bigMargin-|"];

    [scrollView_ addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:verticalConstraints
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:metrics
                                                                          views:views]];

}
```

`MyCollectionViewCell` creates all its controls in its `initWithFrame` method, and here is the method to return the cell.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:[MyCollectionViewCell collectionCellIdentifier]
                                                                           forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Data filling

    return cell;   
}
```

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977896/xcode-collectionviewcontroller-scrolltoitematindexpath-not-working

Comment: Precisely those things are the things I tried before. What do I have to see there?

Comment: Couple of questions: have you checked what are you returning from `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:`? (in the collection view and in the layout). Maybe you are getting something you don’t expect. Second: have you tried to use `setContentOffset:animated:` directly in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`? Just put some numbers, and look if the scroll view does move or not. Cheers.

Comment: @yonosoytu I've edited the question. I don't know if the response of the `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath` is the expected one. Setting the contentOffset does nothing.

Comment: Well, at least you have your reason why it doesn’t move… the layout thinks the second cell is at `0, 0`. I was testing with a standard flow layout and the `setContentOffset:` does work for me in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, but from your edit it might seem that the layout is not even done at that point. You should try to print the `contentSize` of the `UICollectionView` at several points in the VC lifecycle.

Comment: I do what you're attempting to do with no issues in both iOS6 and iOS7. As @yonosoytu suggests, it sounds like your layout isn't ready. Any chance you can share more code?

Comment: I've updated the question again. Thank you all for all your help :-)

Comment: Try to do the scrolling in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` but only when the `contentSize` is not `0, 0`. Something is happening between those two calls that calculates the layout. Another thing you can do is put a breakpoint in some of the layout delegate methods, and see where in your code the layout is really being calculated.

Comment: Can you post the code you have in `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath` please.

Comment: @jhilgert00 I don't have that method implemented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem and could solve it. First of all, when you create the **UICollectionView** you must specify a frame with its width, no matters the height, but the width it's very important to scroll to the correct item.

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
collectionView_ = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth([scrollView_ frame]), 0.0f)
                                     collectionViewLayout:layout];
[collectionView_ setDelegate:self];
[collectionView_ setDataSource:self];
[collectionView_ setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[collectionView_ setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[collectionView_ setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[collectionView_ setPagingEnabled:YES];
[scrollView_ addSubview:collectionView_];
```

After creating the **UICollectionView** you must tell the view that needs update its constraints, because in iOS6 you have to force it, so invoke updateViewConstraints:

```
[self updateViewConstraints]
```

Override the method updateViewConstraints, and set here all the view constraints. Remember to remove all the constraints of the view before invoke super (in your code you are not removing them), and set on metrics' dictionary the **width** of the UICollectionView and don't use *[collectionView_(==scrollView_)]* because sometimes it fails, mainly in iOS6.

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints {

    [scrollView_ removeConstraints:[scrollView_ constraints]];
    [super updateViewConstraints];

    NSDictionary *views = [self viewsDictionary];
    NSDictionary *metrics = @{ @"bigMargin" : @12, @"collectionViewHeight" : @(collectionViewHeight_), @"viewWidth" : @(CGRectGetWidth([scrollView_ frame]) };

    NSMutableString *verticalConstraints = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"V:|[collectionView_(==collectionViewHeight)]"];

    [scrollView_ addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[collectionView_(==viewWidth)]|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:views]];

    if (extendedInformationView_) {

        [scrollView_ addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[extendedInformationView_(==scrollView_)]|"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                            metrics:nil
                                                                              views:views]];

        [verticalConstraints appendFormat:@"-bigMargin-[extendedInformationView_]"];
    }

    if (actionListView_) {

        [scrollView_ addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[actionListView_(==scrollView_)]|"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                            metrics:nil
                                                                              views:views]];

        [verticalConstraints appendFormat:@"-bigMargin-[actionListView_]"];
    }

    [verticalConstraints appendString:@"-bigMargin-|"];

    [scrollView_ addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:verticalConstraints
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:metrics
                                                                          views:views]];

}
```

Finally, to scroll the UICollectionView to the correct item, do it on **viewWillLayoutSubviews** and don't forget to check if UICollectionView's size is **not zero** to avoid app crash:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    if (!CGSizeEqualToSize([collectionView_ frame].size, CGSizeZero)) {

        [collectionView_ scrollToItemAtIndexPath:_selectedRowItem_ inSection:0]
                                atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft
                                        animated:NO];
    }
}
```

That's all. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

The frame of your collection view initially is CGRectZero, for the flow-layout to work it needs to have a collection view with a frame. This seems to happen when you update the layout constraints which is too late in the view life-cycle.

```
collectionView_ = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds collectionViewLayout:layout];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I've been able to reproduce your problem.
The problem is that `UICollectionView` doesn't know about its content size at the moment you are trying to scroll to specified `NSIndexPath`.

Here's a code to reproduce problem:

```
@interface TLCollectionViewController : UIViewController

@end

@interface CollectionCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *titleLbl;

@end

@implementation CollectionCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _titleLbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];

        [_titleLbl setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_titleLbl];

        NSArray *titleLblHConstrArr = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[titleLbl]|" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil views:@{ @"titleLbl" : _titleLbl }];
        NSArray *titleLblVConstrArr = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[titleLbl]|" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil views:@{ @"titleLbl" : _titleLbl }];

        [[self contentView] addConstraints:titleLblHConstrArr];
        [[self contentView] addConstraints:titleLblVConstrArr];

        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.titleLbl.text = @"";
}

@end

@interface TLCollectionViewController () <UICollectionViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *items;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UICollectionView *collView;

@end

@implementation TLCollectionViewController

- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.items = @[ @"one", @"two", @"three", @"one", @"two", @"three", @"one", @"two", @"three"
                    , @"one", @"two", @"three", @"one", @"two", @"three", @"one", @"two", @"three", @"one", @"two", @"three"
                    , @"one", @"two", @"three", @"one", @"two", @"three", @"one", @"two", @"three", @"one", @"two", @"three"
                    , @"one", @"two", @"three", @"one", @"two", @"three", @"one", @"two", @"three", @"one", @"two", @"three"
                    , @"one", @"two", @"three", @"one", @"two", @"three", @"one", @"two", @"three", @"one", @"two", @"three"
                    , @"one", @"two", @"three", @"one", @"two", @"three", @"one", @"two", @"three", @"one", @"two", @"three"
                    , @"one", @"two", @"three", @"one", @"two", @"three", @"one", @"two", @"three", @"one", @"two", @"three"
                    , @"one", @"two", @"three", @"one", @"two", @"three", @"one", @"two", @"three", @"one", @"two", @"three" ];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    self.collView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [self.collView setDataSource:self];
    [self.collView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.collView registerClass:[CollectionCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collCell"];

    [self.view addSubview:self.collView];

    NSArray *collViewHConstrArr = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[collView(==300)]" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil views:@{ @"collView" : self.collView }];
    NSArray *collViewVConstrArr = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[collView(==300)]" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil views:@{ @"collView" : self.collView }];

    [self.view addConstraints:collViewHConstrArr];
    [self.view addConstraints:collViewVConstrArr];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // BUG: here on iOS 6 exception is raised, because UICollectionView doesn't know about it's content size and about it's frame
    // but on iOS 7 it does know about it's frame, thus makes it possible to know about attributes
    id attr = [self.collView layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:70 inSection:0]];
    [self.collView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:70 inSection:0]
                          atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft
                                  animated:NO];
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.items.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.titleLbl.text = self.items[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

This behaviour is different on iOS 6 and iOS 7.
In iOS 6 if you try to get attributes with `UICollectionView` that doesn't have content size **or** frame, you'll get an `NSInternalInconsistencyException` exception. As for iOS 7 this was somehow changed, and now you have to know neither about `UICollectionView` content size, nor about it's frame in order to get attributes for specific `NSIndexPath`.

Regarding call of `-[UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:]` - this method gets called automatically while trying to perform any kind of scrolling of `UICollectionView`.

[image]

To answer your question:

> Is it impossible to show the correct item on appear?

Yes, it is impossible to do it there. You have to know layout in order to be able to scroll correctly. Correct way to perform scroll is to implement it in `-[UIViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews]`:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.collView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:70 inSection:0]
                      atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft
                              animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: In `viewDidLayoutSubviews` it does not work, I tried it the first time. There is no crash, but the item shown while appearing is the first one, and then moves to the new one while completely appeared. That is not the desired behavoir. Thanks.

Comment: This is weird because I am getting scrolled layout if I implement `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method at the moment everything appears.
I think that this is because I have simple `UICollectionViewCell` with just one label, so drawing doesn't take too long, and at the moment view appears - collection view is scrolled. Do you have any complex view hierarchy in your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass?

Comment: Yes, the layout of the cell is kind of complex :(

Comment: @emenegro then you should preserve cells themselves in order to get smoother experience. If this action is performed multiple times (drawing of the cells) then you should somehow cache them (their subviews or their layout) and just re-add it on re-creation. __Warning__: this may cause memory issues due to the fact that cells view will not be released (but you _can_ release it's contents - like so: text, images)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that UIKit would crash when **-scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:Animated** is called when the **UICollectionView** is not yet laid out, as you could see on [Radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/13416281)

So you can only put it in **viewDidAppear and** and **viewDidLayoutSubviews** on iOS7 and only put it in **viewDidAppear** on iOS6. why even **viewDidLayoutSubviews** is excluded on  iOS6 is shown in your log:

```
2013-12-09 08:56:59.300 - didLoad {0, 0}
2013-12-09 08:56:59.315 - willAppear {0, 0}
2013-12-09 08:56:59.350 - viewDidLayoutSubviews {0, 0}
2013-12-09 08:56:59.781 - viewDidLayoutSubviews {3200, 223}
2013-12-09 08:56:59.879 - didAppear {3200, 223}
2013-12-09 08:56:59.882 - viewDidLayoutSubviews {3200, 223}
```

When the first time **viewDidLayoutSubviews** is called, **UICollectionView** is not yet laid out. iOS7 just work in the second time **viewDidLayoutSubviews** is called, but iOS 6 will crash at the first time.

Answer (score 1):

This is where a random extra retain would work in the olden days. I've had it a few times where memory is deallocated and reallocated so the app is looking for something at an address that has been recycled leading to an internal inconsistency error.

There is probably a far better way to add a strong (a __strong probably) it but I try to keep properties like this as, well, properties and:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UICollectionView *collectionView_;
```

Will keep a strong reference to the data hopefully stopping the inconsistency thing.

Martin

Answer (score 1):

This may be related.

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: NSNotFound inSection: index]
```

Use NSNotFound instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that collection view content is loaded in viewWillAppear. CollectionView/TableView will load the data when view is appeared on the screen. Try scroll to item in **viewDidAppear:** method or use some delay.